Do Gukesh & Ding eat dinner?
As I write this question, the World Chess Championship 2024 is going on. Games begin at 5pm local time and go for several hours, followed by a press conference.
This timing sounds like it clashes with most people's dinner time. Do Gukesh & Ding eat dinner? I'm aware that there's a room where they can get food during a game, but that seems like a subpar use of thinking time.

I think they both said in post-game interview after round 7 (or 8 ?) that after the game they have a short dinner and go sleep after.
